# GoogleSpeed insight leverage browser cache

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, caching

I working for google speed insight and it is asking for Leverage browser caching

I have add the code in .htaccess as below

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
   ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
   ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
   ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

js files are not taking effect and my js files content-type are application/javascript as i checked these through inspectelement.

what is wrong with my code? i also have tried with

but it is not improving any more and expiry date is not being adding to files.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: You _also have tried with_ ... ??

Comment: Yes i have tried with above code and text/javascript and application/x-javascript too.. but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to add, in your code, the tags as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c> 
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
   ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
   ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

Add your lines inside the mod_expires Apache module tags.